# The generalized eigenvectors of linear operator $T$ span space $V$, why?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm studying about determinant and I have a problem understanding the following (Proposition 3.4):

[image]

The problems I have are highlighted with red rectangles. If anyone can, could you clarify these points for me? For example in the first rectangle, why does there exist such a $u$. On the second, where does the implication come from, etc.

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commenting on the highlighted rectangels in order of appearance.

1. That's what it means for $v$ to be in the range of $(T-\lambda I)^n$.
2. Here $v\in V_1$, so $(T-\lambda I)^n v=0$. Plug in $v=(T-\lambda I)^n u$.
3. The previous item means that $u$ is a generalized eigenvector of $T$.[ My recollection is that a *generalized eigenvector of a matrix $T$* is a vector annihilated by some power of $(T-\lambda I)$.] Therefore Lemma 3.1. allows us to replace the exponent $2n$ with $n$.
4. Have you seen a general result tying together the dimensions of the range, kernel an domain of a linear transformation? This very useful result is sometimes referred to as *rank-nullity theorem* (=aste-nulliteettilause in Finnish).

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer :) You can see Lemma 3.1 in the top of the picture :) No I have not, I will look into it :) Thank you

Comment: Sorry about missing Lemma 3.1. Thinking... Editing....

Comment: No problem :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just to be sure...what does 'sp' mean in your point 2.? :)

Comment: It means that my accuracy in hitting the correct keys on my laptop is dire.